# cffile vs file function, which is better?

Tags: performance, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

Since ColdFusion 8, there have been functions that interact with files but before there was only the cffile tag.

Now that I have upgraded to ColdFusion 10, which one should I use, the cffile tag or the file function? Does one offer better performance than the other?

For example, should I use `cffile action = "write"` or should I use `fileWrite()`?

Comment: Don't worry about performance: the actual file operation will have orders of magnitude higher performance consideration than vagaries of the syntax. As for which to use? I'd never use a tag unless it was in a view... and file ops code doesn't belong in views. So I'd *always* use the function. However this is pretty subjective (hence the question being closed by a busy-body, I guess).

Comment: Nominating to reopen given syntactical considerations are entirely reasonable lines of enquiry in CFML, and the answer(s) to this question would be valuable to the CFML community & Stack Overflow. Subjective answers are no less meaningful than objective ones. Stack Overflow's rules here are a bit thuggish.

Comment: My assumption (and I could definitely be wrong here) is that the tag and functions end up calling the same underlying Java methods behind the scenes anyway. I am voting to reopen as well because I would like to know the answer to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my guess. I suspect that `<cffile action="read">` is not implemented in the same way as `fileopen()` and `fileread()`. I believe this because the cfscript version can have a file variable whereas the tag version cannot. Therefore, they are different.

I suspect that `FileRead(fileobj [, buffersize])` would be faster because it does not combine the opening and reading operation into one

Answer (score 1):

I strongly believe that there is no difference in between both of them at the performance scale.

One thing that showed up during the million times loop test is the tag timeout issue. `<cffile>` threw a `requesttimeout` to me, while the `fileWrite()` function did not.

Just based on this observation, I can say that, the `<cffile>` does have a *slight* overhead of `requesttimeout` check every time. peanuts.

Apart from that + some help in reducing the file size by removing all those `<cf` prefix and `"` around attributes, I recommend seeing them equally. my 2 cents.